# How to convert first 4 characters of the string p="11.04GET /update?api_key=Q6YVHKEEEKA" to float in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, types

How to convert the first 4 characters of the below string to a float in python?

```
p="11.04GET /update?api_key=Q6BCBDA"
```

Thanks

Comment: Use Slicing - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html and built-in float() - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float

Comment: Consider removing constants from the question subject. People can't find this question because the don't have the same strings given. Also please consider to use code blocks in the question body for better separation text from code.

Answer (score 2):

Note that 1st 4 characters is "11.0" if you want "11.04" you need 5 characters

To get substring, you can use `p[0:5]`

To convert then to float you can use `float(p[0:5])`